# Bundling seperate python modules to create a "Package"

Tags: python, module, package

I have been creating a few modules organized by purpose, and each module contain a number number of functions.  I would like to bundle these individual modules into a larger "package" that other users can import from a shared location.

Currently, I have all of my modules in one folder, called `python_modules` and I have appended this path to `os.path` so I can easily import my individual modules as needed.

However, I would like to instead import a single package, that contains all of my modules, so I don't have to import each one individually.  I know that I could put all my modules into one file, but that doesn't seem like a good way to organize my processes.

Currently, I have to following files in my `python_modules` folder:

```
__init__.py
load_data_functions.py 
parse_data_functions.py   
network_functions.py
counting_function.py    
math_functions.py
...
...
other_functions.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty and does not have anything inside of it.  The other modules all have various functions inside of them, and some are dependent on others.  For example, `network_functions.py` relies on `load_data_functions.py` and `parse_data_functions.py`.

As I said, I want to package all of these modules into a larger package that I can share with others, and so we don't have to import each module independently.

Answer (score 0):

A Package is just a bunch of modules. You already have an `__init__.py` file, so `python_modules` is already a package. You should simply be able to import `python_modules` and then call functions from each individual module as `load_data_functions.some_function()`, `parse_data_functions.some_other_function()`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming "I would like to instead import a single package" means you want to be able to something like:

```
import python_modules

port = python_modules.network_functions.get_port()
```

your `__init__.py` file should look like:

```
from . import load_data_functions
from . import parse_data_functions
from . import network_functions
...
```

if you'd like to be able to do:

```
import python_modules

port = python_modules.get_port()
```

your `__init__.py` file should look like:

```
from .load_data_functions import *
from .parse_data_functions import *
from .network_functions import *
...
```

As for modules within the package referring to each other, you can use the same idea, e.g. at the top of `network_funtions.py` you'd want put `from . import load_data_functions`. You should structure things as to avoid circular imports.